# Can airport X Ray damage rMBP?

Tags: macbook-pro

I was wondering if the X Ray machines at the airport can damage laptops (specifically a rMBP..) or their components (SSD, Battery and so on....)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about the carry-on scanners the answer is no.

I'd be very surprised if the hold baggage scanners had any effect either.

In the past I've irradiated a variety of computers and devices with energies and doses in excess of what a regular airport carry-on baggage scanner offers.

[This FDA item](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/SecuritySystems/ucm116421.htm) might offer some independent reassurance